# R - How can I loop through a list of variables?

Tags: r, loops

I am relatively new to R (and all programming, really), so please excuse what I assume is a very basic question. I have gone through the related discussions on this and many other sites, and I just cannot piece the information together. I am hoping that an example based on my current problem will help me to finally understand how to write this.

- I have a 30*30 data frame called "data1" and the variables (columns) are labeled X1-X30
- "data1" has column labels from which I created a list called "mylist"
- I have another data frame of just one column and 30 rows called "data"
- The one variable (column) in "data" is labeled "SumScores"
- I need to calculate the correlation between each variable in "data1" and "SumScores"
- I want to save only the estimate (cor.test$estimate) from the correlation results to a vector, which I have named "LISTpb"
- I have figured out how to do this by writing the code for each variable
- Will someone please demonstrate for me how to accomplish this task using a loop?

> pb <- cor.test(data1$X1,data$SumScores)$estimate
>
> LISTpb <- pb
>
> pb <- cor.test(data1$X2,data$SumScores)$estimate
>
> LISTpb <- rbind(LISTpb,pb)
>
> LISTpb
>
> pb <- cor.test(data1$X3,data$SumScores)$estimate
>
> LISTpb <- rbind(LISTpb,pb)
>
> LISTpb
>
> pb <- cor.test(data1$X4,data$SumScores)$estimate
>
> LISTpb <- rbind(LISTpb,pb)
>
> LISTpb
>
> pb <- cor.test(data1$X5,data$SumScores)$estimate
>
> LISTpb <- rbind(LISTpb,pb)
>
> LISTpb

Thank you, in advance, to anyone and everyone who can help me with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here one option using `sapply`:

```
sapply(data1,
       function(x) cor.test(x,data$SumScores)$estimate)
```

This will loop over the column of data1, and apply the anonym function where I call  `cor.test`.

You should also read `?apply` ,`?lapply` ,.. and other xxapply family functions. It is the R way (functional paradigm) to do loops.

Here an example using `cars` sample data.frame:

```
sapply(cars,function(x) cor.test(x,cars[,1])$estimate)
speed.cor  dist.cor 
1.0000000 0.8068949
```

Comment: Thank you, agstudy! Your code worked perfectly. I had not been able to figure out the apply family functions before, but I think I am starting to understand it now.